Magento 2: Add Wysiwyg to dynamic fields in System Configuration
I need to add a wysiwyg editor to dynamic fields on the system configuration, the issue is that the editor never render, this is the code i have so far:
system.xml
<group id="diagnosis" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Sección diagnóstico</label>
            <field id="diagnosis_title" translate="label" type="editor" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Título del diagnóstico</label>
                <comment>Introduce el texto del diagnóstico.</comment>
                <frontend_model>G4A\ObstructiveSleepApnea\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\Editor</frontend_model>
            </field>
            <field id="diagnosis_list_box" type="text" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Síntomas</label>
                <frontend_model>G4A\ObstructiveSleepApnea\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\DiagnosisList</frontend_model>
                <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>
            </field>
        </group>

<?php
namespace G4A\ObstructiveSleepApnea\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field;

use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config as WysiwygConfig;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class DiagnosisList extends AbstractFieldArray
{
  
    protected $_wysiwygConfig;
    protected $_wysiwygRenderer;
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        WysiwygConfig $wysiwygConfig,
        array $data = [],
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    protected function _prepareToRender()
    {
        // $this->addColumn('diagnosis1', ['label' => __('Diagnóstico parte 1'), 'class' => 'required-entry']);
        // $this->addColumn('diagnosis2', ['label' => __('Diagnóstico parte 2'), 'class' => 'required-entry']);
        $this->addColumn('wysiwyg_field', [
            'label' => __('Diágnostico'),
            'renderer' => $this->_getWysiwygRenderer()
        ]);
        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Agregar');
    }

    protected function _getWysiwygRenderer()
    {
        if (!$this->_wysiwygRenderer) {
            $this->_wysiwygRenderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'G4A\ObstructiveSleepApnea\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\Editor',
                //'G4A\ObstructiveSleepApnea\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\Wysiwyg',
                '',
                ['data' => ['is_render_to_js_template' => true]]
            );
        }
        //\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->info(print_r($this->_wysiwygRenderer , true));
        return $this->_wysiwygRenderer;
    }


}

<?php
namespace G4A\ObstructiveSleepApnea\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config as WysiwygConfig;
use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field as FormFIeld;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;

class Editor extends FormField
{
    protected $_wysiwygConfig;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        WysiwygConfig $wysiwygConfig,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _getElementHtml(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $element->setWysiwyg(true);
        $config = $this->_wysiwygConfig->getConfig(['tab_id' => $element->getId()]);
        //\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->info(print_r($config, true));
        $element->setConfig($config);
        return parent::_getElementHtml($element);
    }

}


Any hint is apreciated.

@Carlos A Magaña Perez
Hey,
Step 1: Create a Custom Module
Create the module directory structure:
app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/

Create the registration.php file:
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'YourVendor_YourModule',
    __DIR__
);

Create the module.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="YourVendor_YourModule" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>

Step 2: Add System Configuration
Create the system.xml file in app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/etc/adminhtml/:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="your_section" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Your Section Label</label>
            <tab>general</tab>
            <resource>Magento_Config::config</resource>
            <group id="your_group" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Your Group Label</label>
                <field id="your_field" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Your Field Label</label>
                    <frontend_model>YourVendor\YourModule\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\Wysiwyg</frontend_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>

Create the Wysiwyg.php file in
app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Form/Field/:
<?php

namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;
use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field;

class Wysiwyg extends Field
{
    protected function _getElementHtml(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $element->setWysiwyg(true);
        $element->setConfig($this->_getWysiwygConfig());

        return parent::_getElementHtml($element);
    }

    protected function _getWysiwygConfig()
    {
        $config = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $config->setData([
            'enabled' => true,
            'hidden' => false,
            'use_container' => true,
            'add_variables' => true,
            'add_widgets' => true,
            'add_images' => true,
            'files_browser_window_url' => $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl('cms/wysiwyg_images/index'),
        ]);

        return $config;
    }
}

Step 3: Add JavaScript to Enable WYSIWYG
Create requirejs-config.js in app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/view/adminhtml/:
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            wysiwygSetup: 'YourVendor_YourModule/js/wysiwyg-setup'
        }
    }
};

Create wysiwyg-setup.js in app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/view/adminhtml/web/js/:
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup'
], function ($, wysiwygSetup) {
    'use strict';

    return function (config) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            wysiwygSetup(config);
        });
    };
});

Step 4: Update Your system.xml to Use JavaScript
Update your system.xml field to include wysiwygSetup:
<field id="your_field" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Your Field Label</label>
    <frontend_model>YourVendor\YourModule\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\Wysiwyg</frontend_model>
    <frontend_type>wysiwyg</frontend_type>
    <config_path>your_vendor/your_module/your_field</config_path>
</field>

Step 5: Flush Cache
After creating these files, flush the Magento cache to make sure your changes are applied:
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento cache:flush

Verification
Navigate to the Magento admin panel, go to Stores > Configuration, and find your custom section. You should see your dynamic fieldset with the WYSIWYG editor applied to it.
Thank You!
